# como creo una columna calculada en sql sumando un numero entero a una fecha

Tags: mysql

Buen día para todos.

veran tengo una base de datos donde ingreso informacion desde un formulario en especifico el campo es `fechaCompra` (tipo date) y tengo otro donde pongo cuanto tiempo tiene de garantia en meses (int), lo que quiero hacer es crear una columna que sume el valor de `(garantia * 30)+ fechaCompra` y el resultado lo muestre en tipo date.

probe con esta sentencia,

```
ALTER TABLE activos ADD fechaVencimiento DATE AS DATEADD(DAY,+(garantia*30),fechaCompra)
```

pero no me funciona.

tambien he intentado sumarle dias (`ALTER TABLE activos ADD fechaVencimiento DATE AS ((garantia*30)+fechaCompra)`) pero no me sale valor `0000-00-00`

de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con el mes de febrero, o los meses de 31 días? y, ¿por qué intentas resolver esto con `ALTER TABLE`, estás normalizando?

Comment: no es nada a gran escala, es un pequeño proyecto que me encuentro desarrollando, los puntos que me cuestionas estoy aprendiendo y si tienes algún consejo me seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` lo que hace es modificar (alterar) la tabla y suele usarse cuando quieres normalizar una situación, como por ejemplo agregar una columna que no existe. Por otra parte, en MySQL la función se llama `DATE_ADD`. Si tú quieres agregar `N` días a una fecha tendrías que hacer algo así: `DATE_ADD(fechaCompra,INTERVAL (garantia*30) DAY)`, revisa el [Manual de Referencia para más detalles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate). La sintaxis que usas actualmente no es correcta.

Comment: muchas gracias por la info

Comment: Debe funcionar con `fechaVencimiento DATE as ( fechaCompra +interval garantia*30 day )`

Comment: asi me funciono, muchas gracias